# select in mongodb all usernames where array field exist in id

Tags: mongodb, select

this are the fields in collection coll_users

```
_id // ObjectID
username // type string
password // type string
friend_id // array number ( ids of friends)
user_id // Number (my id)
```

ok,I want select all usernames from coll_users that exist in the friend_id, I mean?

db.coll_users.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51aaba74e747509139beed9b"), "friend_id" : [ 2, 3, 55, 56 ], "password" : "something", "user_id" : 1, "username" : "something" }
```

I want to do is to select all users where user_id exist in friend_id of collection

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation framework:

```
db.coll_users.aggregate( [ 
   {$unwind : "$friend_id"},
   {$project: { selfAsFriend: {$eq:["$user_id","$friend_id"]}, user_id:1 } },
   {$match  : { selfAsFriend : true } }
] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
db.coll_users.find( { "_id" : ObjectId("51aaba74e747509139beed9b"), 
    "friend_id" : { $in : [ 2, 3, 55, 56 ] }, "password" : "something", "user_id" : 1, 
    "username" : "something" }, 
    {"username" : 1 } )
```

Comment: mmm no, because I wanna select all user that user_id = friend_id

Comment: I wanna sellect all usarname of user_id= 2, user_id=3, user_id=55 and user_id=56

Comment: Do you mean a user that is a friend of him/herself?